# I have a word or sentence ,Is there any way/open-source package to find the probability that user has spoken that word

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, speech, kaldi

I have a word /sentence ,Is there any way/open-source package to find the probability that user has spoken that word / sentence

Answer (score 2):

The most commonly used free speech recognition toolkits are:

1. Kaldi
2. CMU Sphinx

Working with Python it is pretty simple to set up a basic speech recognition system using [pocketsphinx-python](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-python). A little bit more tricky but in my experience with better result is to set up a system with Kaldi using for example [kaldi-gstreamer-server](https://github.com/alumae/kaldi-gstreamer-server).

Another option is to use an API like:

- Microsoft Bing Speech
- Google Cloud Speech
- IBM Speech to Text

A great entry point to check them out is this [SpeechRecognition](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/) python library. However, keep in mind that for these services you will need an API key.

In your case, you say you have a given sentence and want to get the probability that exactly this sentence was said. This is a little different than the general speech recognition task since you have more prior information which can make your estimation more accurate. For this problem the commonly used term is **Keyword Detection** and you can try using [Keyword Lists](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutoriallm/#keyword-lists) with CMU Sphinx.